# Подсчет общего времени в dateEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qtablewidget

Есть код, который отсчитывает данные от последней даты указанной в `dataEdit`, но мне нужно чтобы он показывал дату от первого значения.

Как такого добиться?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Widget(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("UI_lke2.ui", self)


        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(

                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
            )

            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):

        if row == 0:
            dateTime1 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row + 1, 0).dateTime()
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
            self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row + 1, 1, item)
            return

        dateTime1 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row - 1, 0).dateTime()
        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
        self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)

        if row != self.tableWidget_3.rowCount() - 1:
            dateTime1 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row + 1, 0).dateTime()
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, dateTime1.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
            self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row + 1, 1, item)


    def buttonLoader(self):
        pass
        data_for_word = []
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            dateTime = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
            item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data = item.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            data_for_word.append([dateTime, _data])

        print(f'\n{data_for_word}\n')
        print(*data_for_word, sep='\n')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил для вас блок, который надо изменить.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Widget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("UI_lke2.ui", self)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), 
                QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
            )
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)

        for row in range(self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()):
            date_from = QDateTimeEdit()
            date_from.setDateTime(
                QDateTime(QDate(2021, 9, 2))
            )
            date_from.dateTimeChanged.connect(
                lambda dateTime, row=row: self.date_changed(dateTime, row))
            self.tableWidget_3.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)
            
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv            
        self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(0, 0).dateTime()   # !!!

    def date_changed(self, dateTime, row):
        if row == 0:
            self.dateTime0 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
            for row in range(1, self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()): 
                dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
                item = QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, 
                    self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)            
                self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)
            return

        dateTime2 = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0).dateTime()
        item = QTableWidgetItem()
        item.setData(Qt.DisplayRole, 
            self.dateTime0.secsTo(dateTime2) / 60. / 60.)
        self.tableWidget_3.setItem(row, 1, item)

# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def buttonLoader(self):
        pass
        data_for_word = []
        rows = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
        cols = self.tableWidget_3.columnCount()
        for row in range(rows):
            dateTime = self.tableWidget_3.cellWidget(row, 0). \
                dateTime().toString('dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm')
            item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row, 1)
            _data = item.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
            data_for_word.append([dateTime, _data])

        print(f'\n{data_for_word}\n')
        print(*data_for_word, sep='\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UI_lke2.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>320</width>
    <height>240</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget_3">
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <row>
       <property name="text">
        <string>3</string>
       </property>
      </row>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </column>
      <column>
       <property name="text">
        <string>2</string>
       </property>
      </column>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>320</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]